# Install nested dependencies from custom index

Tags: python, pipenv

We're trying to use pipenv and faced issue with nested relationships from custom PyPI. For example, Pipenv file of current project contains something like:

```
[[source]]
name = "custom"
url = "http://some.custom.pypi/simple"
verify_ssl = false

[packages]
lib-a = {version = "==1.2.3", index = "custom"}
```

Meantime, this `lib-a` also depends on another library from the same custom index, say, `lib-b`. Issue that pipenv of current project doesn't know that `lib-b` should be found in custom index, and generated Pipfile.lock doesn't have "index" entry for `lib-b`. As a result, dependency cannot be installed.

So, question is, is it possible somehow to let pipenv know "index" of `lib-b` without explicit mentioning in Pipfile? Currently we cannot modify `lib-b`, but we may have this ability if we can proof that changes will fix our issue. Unfortunately, we cannot just try to use pipenv in `lib-b` project without proofs, and we didn't find such information in documentation.

Comment: My unfortunate temporary bypass to this was to specifically specify `lib-b` in the pipfile whenever I just need `lib-a`